# STM32 USB Mass Storage on External OSPI Flash

Tags: usb, stm32, flash, usb-device, hal-library

**Hardware Target:** I am using the STM32L4R9IDISCOVERY board

[image]

**Achievement 1:** Building a little-fs file system, reading & writing files in the OSPI Flash memory with these functions:

```
int block_device_read(const struct lfs_config *c, lfs_block_t block,
    lfs_off_t off, void *buffer, lfs_size_t size)
{
    BSP_OSPI_NOR_Read((uint8_t*) buffer, (block * c->block_size + off), size);
    return 0;
}
int block_device_prog(const struct lfs_config *c, lfs_block_t block,
    lfs_off_t off, const void *buffer, lfs_size_t size)
{
    BSP_OSPI_NOR_Write((uint8_t*)buffer, (block * c->block_size + off), size);
    return 0;
}
int block_device_erase(const struct lfs_config *c, lfs_block_t block)
{
    BSP_OSPI_NOR_Erase_Block(block);
    return 0;
}
int block_device_sync(const struct lfs_config *c)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Achievement 2:** To be able to load the USB Device Mass Storage Stack & use it with RAM Memory, configuring correctly the *usbd_storage_if.c* file:

```
uint8_t buffer[STORAGE_BLK_NBR*STORAGE_BLK_SIZ];

int8_t STORAGE_Read_FS(uint8_t lun, uint8_t *buf, uint32_t blk_addr, uint16_t blk_len)
{
  memcpy(buf, &buffer[blk_addr*STORAGE_BLK_SIZ], blk_len*STORAGE_BLK_SIZ);
}
int8_t STORAGE_Write_FS(uint8_t lun, uint8_t *buf, uint32_t blk_addr, uint16_t blk_len)
{
  memcpy(&buffer[blk_addr*STORAGE_BLK_SIZ], buf, blk_len*STORAGE_BLK_SIZ);
}
```

**Functional target:**
Now, I am trying to use the OSPI External Flash with a USB Device access. I would like to be able to plug the board on my computer to detect it as a USB Mass Storage so using FATFS and not little-fs

The OSPI Flash memory is the same 512Mbit NOR Flash (Ref MX25LM51245G).

I don't find how to code the same STORAGE_Read_FS & STORAGE_Write_FS functions. With many tries, sometimes the USB device is not recognized and some times I am not able to format the file system. How to adapt my BSP_OSPI_NOR_Write & BSP_OSPI_NOR_Read functions to these USB functions?

**Additional information:** The flash internal configuration is the following:

```
#define MX25LM51245G_FLASH_SIZE                   0x4000000 /* 512 MBits => 64 MBytes */
#define MX25LM51245G_BLOCK_SIZE                   0x10000   /* 1024 blocks of 64 KBytes */
#define MX25LM51245G_SECTOR_SIZE                  0x1000    /* 16384 sectors of 4 kBytes */
#define MX25LM51245G_PAGE_SIZE                    0x100     /* 262144 pages of 256 bytes */
```